# Using Cast to Convert DateTime to Date and select today's date

Tags: sql, reportbuilder3.0

I'm trying to count the number of accounts opened on today's date in the SELECT Statement.  I'm doing so with an IIF statement and using CAST to convert the DateTimeStamp to Date. That said, I'm having trouble figuring out where to date column (Open_Date) and how to check to see if it's is today's date. Would I place -1 right after the ) following as date or???

```
COUNT(IIF(CAST(GETDATE() AS date))), SHARE.MEMBER_NBR, null)) AS ALLNEWACCOUNTSTODAY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` expression with `Open_Date` :

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) = Open_Date THEN SHARE.MEMBER_NBR END) AS ALLNEWACCOUNTSTODAY
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the architectur please ?
Without it I would suggest that :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Accounts Where CONVERT(date,accountDate)=CONVERT(DATE,getdate());
```

It assumes that you have a column accountDate containing the date you added the account and that this column is into an accounts table.